# Query "Remaining Quota" for Microsoft Cognitive Services APIs programmatically

Tags: api, bing-api, azure-cognitive-services

I am currently using 3 Microsoft APIs: Text Analytics Api, Bing Search Api and Linguistic Api. I want to know if there's any Api or method to retrieve remaining quota programmatically for my specific Api against my Api Key?

Other thing I want to know if any Api or any method of these APIs to tell me programmatically if my key is valid or invalid.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, I do not think there is a way to check you remaining quota. If you are concerned about spending beyond your budget, you may be interested into keeping track of the number of calls you do to Microsoft Cognitive Services. In any case, this is the kind of question I suggest you should directly ask to Microsoft Cognitive Services [customer services](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/).

For the second question, there is no way to do so. If such way would exist, that would encourage malicious users to find it to generate keys at will. Assuming you have an expired key, the only way to verify its validity is to make a call to any of the Microsoft Cognitive Services APIs and check the error code message, if any.

Comment: I have already asked Microsoft Cognitive Services' customer service but my request in is queue yet to be answered. Anyways your answer is well received.

Comment: About 2nd question. It is still possible to brute force any api. For example if I send a valid key with no documents to Text Analytics Api, it will respond with no documents exception not with key invalidity. If key is invalid, it responds with key invalidity.